# Adobe Indesign: How to measure the width of a word?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, extended-scripting

Is it possible to measure the width of a word in some way? (via Javascript code, or a built-in software option)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is to:

- Create a text frame. (Make sure that it has basic appearance without insets.)
- Paste the word you want to measure into the text frame.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to *Fit Frame to Content*.
- Read the width in the *Transform* panel.

[image]

This width includes a tiny space before and after the word which comes from the way the font was designed. If you want the exact width of the geometric shapes, use *Type > Create Outlines* instead of *Fit Frame to Content*.

Although a little hacky, this method can also be used in a script in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this would be to simply draw a line or box and take the measurements from the chosen rule of the line or box.

I'm sure an InDesign whizz will know a plugin for a rule, however this is my quick fix.